# changing Chrome desktop app Cmd-Tab behaviour

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-hangouts

I use the Google Hangouts desktop app. But when i use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it comes under Chrome rather than being a separate application. If I have *Hangouts* and *Chrome* open, I have to use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) to switch between them.

Is there anyway I can move the *Hangouts* app to a separate <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> group?